# MySQL - Using multiply LEFT JOIN statements in the same query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join

I am trying to select data from multiply tables using MySQL. Therefore I am using LEFT JOIN. Although I am having trouble getting the statement correct.

This is my code:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("
            SELECT ur.title, ur.forum_id, urs.*
            FROM forum_topics as ur 
              LEFT JOIN forum_cats as urs 
              ON ur.forum_id=urs.forum_id 
            WHERE ur.topic_id=:topicid
              LEFT JOIN forum_posts as pos
            WHERE pos.post_id=:post



            "
         );
    $stmt->bindParam(':topicid',$postData['topic_id']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':post', $post);
    $stmt->execute();
    $topicData = $stmt->fetch();
```

This is my error message:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN forum_posts as pos
WHERE pos.post_id='5886'
' at line 6' .php</b> on line <b>82</b><br />
```

So, my question is: what is wrong with my MySQL Query?

Comment: You should use one `WHERE` condition and join conditions using `AND` or `OR`.

Comment: AND or OR conditions to specify what data to select? Could you provide an example based on my code?

Comment: What is the joining condition to `forum_posts`? To which other table does it related, and by what common column? You need to specify an `ON` clause for that join...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski It is not related to the other tables - I though using the JOIN functions, I would save to do another query (and therefore another connection to the database)

Comment: @oliverbj No, you can't join without a relationship (well you can, but you get a cartesian product of all tables, which is probably not what you want). You have no columns from `pos` in the `SELECT` list, so if not to join, what did you hope to get from it?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I guess I have misunderstood the JOIN function then. I was not aware that they need to be related. I though you could "gather" queries to one big, instead of opening a new connection all the time and do a query.

Comment: @oliverbj That's sort of the purpose of `UNION`, but you need to make sure all components of the `UNION` return the same number of columns and in the correct expected order. Not recommended to pack together unrelated queries into a UNION just to get one result set back though...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thanks a lot for the explanation! I'll have to read a bit more about these subjects :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use one `WHERE` condition and specify the join condition with `ON` in the second join:

```
SELECT 
  ur.title, 
  ur.forum_id, 
  urs.*
FROM forum_topics as ur 
LEFT JOIN forum_cats as urs 
  ON ur.forum_id=urs.forum_id 
LEFT JOIN forum_posts as pos
  ON (... condition ...)
WHERE ur.topic_id=:topicid
  AND pos.post_id=:post
```

Note I left out the join condition since it's not clear from the question and I guessed you wanted an `AND` in the `WHERE` clause, you can switch to `OR` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `WHERE` after all the joins, on all of the joined tables. Use `ON` or `USING` on all joins.

`USING` is a nice shorthand where the columns are named the same in both tables. It's not only shorter it also removes the duplicate column and makes it possible to, in this case, to use the column forum_id without table prefix.

Like this:

```
SELECT ur.title, 
       ur.forum_id, 
       urs.*
  FROM forum_topics as ur 
  LEFT JOIN forum_cats as urs 
       USING (forum_id)
  LEFT JOIN forum_posts as pos
       USING (forum_id)
 WHERE pos.post_id=:post
   AND topic_id=:topicid
```